# Showing a function is Riemann integrable by upper sum and lower sum

Tags: real-analysis

I am solving the following analysis problem.

Define $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$  f(x) = \begin{cases}
1  ,&  \text{if $1-2^{-2k} \leq x \leq 1-2^{-(2k+1) }$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$}  \\ 
0  ,&  \text{if $1-2^{-(2k+1)} \lt x \lt 1-2^{-(2k+2)}$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$}\\
0  ,&  \text{if $x=1$}\end{cases} \text{.}  $$

Prove that $f$ is integrable on $[0, 1]$, and compute $$\int_{0}^1 f(x)dx.$$

My strategy is to sum up the values with a geometric series. Once I have it I want to pick an epsilon and work with the upper sum and lower sum until I have that

$$L(f) \leq U(f)$$ such that for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists a partition P such that $$L(p,f) -U(p,f) \lt \epsilon$$

work is as follows:

$$L(p,f)=\sum_{i=0}^N inf*(t_k-t_{k-1})$$
$$U(p,f)=\sum_{i=0}^N sup*(t_k-t_{k-1})$$

For the lower sum I have:

$x_i$=$1-2^i$ for $i=0,1,...,N+1$

when $i =0$ $inf=1$

when $i=1$ $inf=0$

when $i=2$ $inf=1$

(upper sum obviously follows)

So,for the upper and lower sum I have:
$$L(p,f)=0+\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} 1_ieven*2^{-i-1}=0+2^{-1}+2^{-3}+...$$
$$U(p,f)=2^{-N-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} 1_i*2^{-i-1}=2^{-N-1}+2^{-1}+2^{-3}...$$

Now, I think my proof up to this point is sound but Im having a hard time computing the sum at the very bottom and could use some help. thanks.

Comment: Why did you delete the old post? I had an answer half done

Comment: I am so sorr, I thought I typed it wrong. please help!

Comment: No worries, please just edit next time

Comment: Notice that in your new answer you've plugged the infimum into your upper sum where you should have plugged in your supremum. Also notice the supremum over each subinterval is $1$ because the subintervals are closed intervals. This is precisely why I did not continue down this line of reasoning in my answer.

Comment: I have made some edits. given those edits, does my proof look correct?

Comment: Your edits don't actually address my issue, you've still plugged the infimum into the form for the upper sum at the bottom.

Comment: I see what you're talking about, but I don't know how to fix it, how do you suggest editing my upper sum statement near the bottom of the proof?

Comment: The supremum over any of your closed subintervals is $1,$ so where you have $1_{i,even}$ it should just be a $1.$ However, this highlights the issue with this approach because now your upper and lower sums will converge to different values. You cannot proceed with this partition, it simply doesn't work.

Comment: There is a way to do this with a partition as you're trying to, but it's a bit more complicated and some of the math gets kind of gross. If you really have to use the Darboux criterion then I completely back Eric's answer, I think he's come up with a really great idea for how to go about it that way, but I still suggest the Lebesgue criterion because the integrability follows directly.

Answer (score 1):

By Lebesgue's integrability condition, a function is Riemann integrable if and only if it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere on the domain of integration. Clearly our function is bounded because $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ for any $x,$ so the main concern is continuity.

Here our function will be continuous everywhere except at points $x = 1 - 2^{-k}$ for nonnegative integers $k.$ So, the set of discontinuities is countably infinite, and so it has a Lebesgue measure of $0,$ which means that the function is continuous almost everywhere.

To see why any countably infinite set has $0$ Lebesgue measure, consider turning the set of points into a sequence $x_n$ using the bijection between the set and the natural numbers. Now consider $I_n = (x_n - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}, x_n + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}})$ for any real $\epsilon > 0.$ We have that $l(I_n) = \frac{\epsilon}{2^n},$ so the sum of the lengths is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\epsilon}{2^n} = \epsilon.$ Because we can do this for any arbitrary $\epsilon > 0,$ the highest possible lower bound for the sum of the lengths, or in other words the Lebesgue measure, is $0.$

Now to compute the integral, consider the function

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}1, \text{if }  1 - 2^{-2k} \leq x \leq 1 - 2^{-2k-1} \text{ for } k \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 \leq k \leq n \\ 0, \text{if }  1 - 2^{-2k-1} \leq x \leq 1 - 2^{-2k-2} \text{ for } k \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 \leq k \leq n \\ 0, \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Clearly we have that $|f_n(x)| \leq f(x)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = f,$ so by the dominated convergence theorem we have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x) dx = \int_0^1 f(x) dx.$

Now notice that for any finite $n,$ we can break up the integral into finitely many subintervals such that $$\int_0^1 f_n(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^n \left[\int_{1 - 2^{-2k}}^{1 - 2^{-2k-1}} f_n(x) dx + \int_{1 - 2^{-2k-1}}^{1 - 2^{-2k-2}} f_n(x) dx\right] = \sum_{k = 0}^n 2^{-2k} - 2^{-2k-1}$$ noting that the integrals for $k > n$ must be zero by the definition of $f_n.$

Now taking the limit as $n$ goes to infinity gives us that $$\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} 2^{-2k} - 2^{-2k-1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} 4^{-k} - \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac12 4^{-k} = \frac43 - \frac23 = \frac23.$$

Intuitively this should make sense, because for any $k$ you look at, $(1 - 2^{-2k}, 1 - 2^{-2k-1})$ is twice as large as $(1 - 2^{-2k-1}, 1 - 2^{-2k-2}),$ so the intervals of the first form should take up two thirds of the space.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why is that you consider that interval?

Comment: Also how is it that l($I_n$)= $\frac {\epsilon}{2}$

Comment: The Lebesgue measure is defined as the minimum (or infimum to be more precise) sum of lengths for a set of open intervals which contain every point in a set. I constructed that interval in particular because it's very clear that $I_n$ contains $x_n$ (it's in the center) and the sum of the lengths converges to a finite sum. As far as why $l(I_n) = \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$... just subtract the upper bound from the lower bound.

Comment: What is the upper bound and lower bound you consider?

Comment: As I said, $I_n = (x_n - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}, x_n + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}})$

Comment: in your proof you wrote, 0 if otherwise. you did take into account that its 0 if x=1, right?

Comment: Yes I did, notice that that is the definition for $f_n,$ not $f.$ I think of $f_n$ as being equal to $f$ for one part of the domain and $0$ for the rest, and then as $n$ gets larger, more and more of the domain is filled in with $f,$ until in the limiting case the entire domain is covered.

Comment: Does $$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} 2^{-2k}$$ describe your uppersum (not including the interval)?

Comment: No, I didn't use the concepts of upper and lower sums.

Comment: Is $$ \sum_{k = 0}^n \left[ \int_{1 - 2^{-2k-1}}^{1 - 2^{-2k-2}} f_n(x) dx\right]=0?$$

Comment: Also, did you not use the concept of upper and lower sums because we do not have one partition? and because by showing the sum is finite, we prove that the function is integrable?

Comment: Proving the function was integrable was already done in the first part of the answer, the rest is focused on evaluating the integral. And yes, the integral is $0$ because the function is always $0$ everywhere within those bounds

Comment: functions with countably infinite and finitely many discontinuous point, are they both covered under this theorem?

Comment: Yes, you can show that a finite set has zero Lebesgue measure by giving each interval a length of $\frac{\epsilon}n$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ where $n$ is the number of points in the set. This gives us a total length of $\epsilon,$ and because $\epsilon$ can get arbitrarily small, the highest lower bound for the total length of the intervals is $0.$

Answer (score 0):

Sketch:

Consider, for $u \in [0,1)$,
$$  I(u) = \int_0^u f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x \text{.}  $$

For each choice of $u$, $I$ has only finitely many discontinuities, so is Riemann integrable.  On $[u,1]$, the minimum of $f(x)$ is $0$ and the maximum is $1$.  So a lower sum on $[u,1]$ has value $0$ and an upper sum has value $1-u$.  Now take the limit as $u \rightarrow 1^-$ to show that $I$ plus the upper sum and $I$ plus the lower sum have the same limit (thus showing that the limit of Riemann sums as the partition diameter goes to zero has that same limit).

Comment: how do you get that the upper sum has value 1-u?

Comment: also, what do you mean by I plus the upper sum and I plus the lower sum?

Comment: and what interval are you choosing?

Comment: @LavoriziaVaughn : $f$ is upper bounded by $1$ on the interval $[u,1]$, having width $1-u$, so the sum has upper bound $1 \cdot (1-u)$.  $I$ is given in the display -- use $I$ on $[0,u]$ + a sum on $[u,1]$ to get upper and lower bounds.